# Different package versions for Android and iOS

Tags: npm, react-native, dependencies, multiple-versions, os-dependent

I am developing an app for both Android and iOS using React Native.

One of the libraries I'm using is a bit problematic because the app only compiles correctly:

- ...on ***Android*** when using `"react-native": "0.42.0"`.
- ...on ***iOS*** when using `"react-native": "0.37.0"`.

<sup>(Neither the library itself , nor the specific versions of `react-native` are important for this discussion. What's important is that I seemingly need two separate versions *"at the same time"* - a different one for each platform.)</sup>

I'm looking for a way to have a single codebase that can compile using the relevant tools for either platform w/o any modification<sup>1</sup>. The solutions I thought of are (to somehow):

- Specify different package versions for each mobile OS.
- Have completely different `package.json` files for each platform.

However, I have no idea how either of the above can be achieved or if they're even possible. I tried adding `.ios` and `.android` as explained in the [React-Native docs on platform-specific code](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html#platform-specific-extensions), but npm doesn't recognize these files.

So my questions are:

1. Are my ideas feasible, and if so - how?
2. Is there any other ways to get the desired result?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> In C-like code, this would've been easy with pre-processor flags.</sup>

Comment: What is the library you are using? I really wouldn't go for having different RN versions on ios/android. The difference between them will turn out really hard to handle at some point. 0.42+ have some bugfixes your ios app is going to miss. Above this you'll have to miss out on new available features. I would go for looking into the library and making it work on 0.42, opening a PR would help as long as the maintainer is on the project.

Comment: @dhorelik - I appreciate your comment. The library itself is being actively developed and I'm sure that eventually this discrepancy will be resolved. My question is of a more general nature, so I specifically didn't mention the library. In this specific case the RN version needs to be different, but it can just as easily be some other dependency. I would like to have a way to resolve a scenario where different library versions are required for some reason (due to some minor functionality change etc.). I think this question could benefit others in the future more if it remains general.

Comment: @Dev-iL I am facing a situation where I am using a package for android and not for iOS, how can I achieve this with single code base without disturbing iOS build?

Comment: @vignesh I'm hardly an expert on the topic, so the only idea that comes to mind is to create a local copy ("version") of the package, then remove the majority of the iOS code from it - so that it complies but has no effect.

Comment: having a similar issue @Dev-iL -- did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Sara unfortunately, no. However, I stopped lookin a long time ago, so maybe there _is_ some solution for this out there by now. Please do post it if you find one...

Answer (score 0):

You can use git branches, so you can keep different versions of your package.json file.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This is one of many possible workarounds which involve changing the files somehow. Note that I specifically requested a solution that "just works" without having to change anything about the code when triggering a build for either environment.

Comment: Precisely you cand do that by writting a startup script. Something like: "git checkout androidbranch && rm -rf node_modules && yarn && yarn android"

Answer (score -1):

Haven't tried it yet, but I'm going to. Someone suggested I try this: "combine npm aliases in `package.json` alongside of platform-specific files that Metro supports (e.g. `Component.ios.js`)"

Possibly something like…

```
{
  "package-v1": "http://example.com/package-v1",
  "package-v2": "http://example.com/package-v2",
   // or GitHub based
  "package-v1": "orgname/package#v1",
  "package-v2": "orgname/package#v2",
}

// Component.ios.js
import "package-v1"

// Component.android.js
import "package-v2"
```